# Using operator<< with const object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a trouble with overloading operator<< for const objects.I couldnt find out the problem

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class T
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,T& t)
    {
        os << "Val : " << t.value << endl;
        return os;
    }
private:
    int value;
public:
    T(int v) { value=v; }
    int getValue() const { return value; }
};

int main()
{
    const T t(2);
    cout << t;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler Message:

> error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'const T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Is there a compiler error message?

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `operator<<()` doesn't work with a `const` object because you have declared it as

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,T& t)
```

You need to tell the compiler that you want to be able to use it with `const` objects:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const T& t)
```

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks for fixing my fat-fingered typo.

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator<<` should typically take its argument by `const` reference:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const T& t)
```

A non-`const` reference cannot bind to a `const` object. This makes sense, otherwise you'd be able to modify the `const` object through the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `T&` a `const` reference in line:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,T& t)
```

So it becomes:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const T& t)
```

Or, get rid of the `&`:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,T t)
```

Both will give the following result with your code:

`Val : 2`

in the console.

Comment: Or make it a `const` reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a const and it should work :

`friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const T& t)`